# how to delete a user click on the button ? - Firebase - Vue.js

Tags: firebase, vue.js

I am trying to delete a user by clicking a button. My delete function is this one:

```
deleteUser(){
  const user = firebase.auth().currentUser;

  this.usersRef.delete(user.uid).then(function() {
    // User deleted.
    console.log("User deleted")
  }).catch(function(error) {
    // An error happened.
    console.log("User NOT deleted")
  });
}
```

but I have this error:

```
this.usersRef.delete is not a function
```

Comment: Have you tried [`user.delete().then(...)`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#delete_a_user)?

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
this.usersRef.delete(user.uid).then(function() {
```

into this:

```
this.usersRef.remove().then(function() {
```

more info here:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#delete_data

Comment: have you checked the answer? @DenisMasot